# Were two brothers killed on the same moped by the same taxi driver, exactly a year apart?

Tags: history, mortality

I was sent an email today with a bunch of "coincidences," many of which are probably false. This one stood out since it has a year and an age (some specifics), so perhaps it has the chance of being looked in to:

> Did you know? In 1975 a 17 year old boy was killed while riding his moped. He was killed exactly a year after his 17 year old brother was killed while riding the same moped, in the same intersection, by the same taxi, with the same driver, carrying the same passenger.

Seems far fetched, so I Googled it. It's making its appearances on [about.com](http://paranormal.about.com/od/humanenigmas/a/Amazing-Coincidences.htm), the [Snopes message boards](http://message.snopes.com/showthread.php?t=24616), and many other websites. The source cited in each case is a book called [Phenomena. A Book of Wonders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LQCFRE) by John Michell & Robert J. M. Rickard.

There's no preview on Amazon and I didn't get any Google image hits for various search strategies (I was hoping to see the actual page with the story).

Is there evidence to suggest this was a real occurrence (aside from it being said to exist in a book)?

Comment: According to google maps, there is a place named Hog Bay in Bermuda, a very short distance from Middle Road. Following Middle Road about 4km north where it changes its name to Somerset Road gets you to a place named "Sandys"; all at the most western part of the island. So the place names are not made up. And with a population of only about 60,000, it is not that unlikely that the same taxi driver would be involved in two accidents.

Comment: This question has definately piqued my interest. It doesn;t fit the usual MO of an urban legend (names, real identifiable places in the area specified, dates etc). It is also, on the face of it, easy to proove or disproove based on the fact that deaths are public record and a death of this nature would surely be identifiable (RTA usually involves death by blunt trauma, for example). To that end I have emailed the Bermuda department responsible for births/deaths - lets see what kind of response I get

Comment: You will also notice something else when looking on the map: Middle Road is part of a long Road that stretches over all islands, it's easy to imagine that the majority of accidents happen on this road.

Comment: Sadly the Bermudan government want $55 to search their death records - even though I provided exact names and dates of death :(

Comment: We bermudians are british so no suprise it is in an uk column. I actually remember hearing of this growing up but it was lost down the road with the hundreds of other fatalities. My advice to visitors would be to stay from the mopeds. its not safe on narrow roads and driving/riding opposite of whatvyou are used to. Its heartbreaking the amount of deaths we have had and us bermudians are very paranoid and super carful riding behind and even infront. But you cant beat the inevitable .

Comment: Something that contradicts the theory: why wasn't the license of the taxi driver confiscated and cancelled after the first accident? How come he was still driving?

Comment: @CiprianBirtea Maybe the accidents (both) were caused by the moped drivers.

Comment: @Lush - I discovered that residents are able to search the database for free if they show up in person - which makes you uniquely able to confirm or deny this claim (see my comments above from May '14)

Answer (score 19):

An article on cracked.com about [coincidences](http://www.cracked.com/article_18788_the-5-most-mind-blowing-coincidences-all-time.html#ixzz311R1ylvZ) includes a newspaper clip taken from the *The Scunthorpe Evening Telegraph* on July 21, 1975:

[image: Newspaper article]

> ## Twin tragedy
>
> Erskine Lawrence Ebbin was knocked down by a taxi and killed in Hamilton, Bermuda — and it was the same taxi with the same driver, carrying the same passanger, that killed his brother Neville in July last year.
>
> And both brothers were riding the same moped and died, aged 17, on the same street, police said.

It is remarkable in that it includes the full name of both brothers (Erskine Lawrence and Neville Ebbin) and the city in which it allegedly happened (Hamilton, Bermuda). This means it should be possible to verify the events by checking official records.

It is still possible that the whole story was made up to fill empty space on the page (notice that the *Scunthorpe Evening Telegraph* is published in the United Kingdom, while the accident is supposed to have happened on Bermuda, difficult to verify for a reader in 1975.)

Based on this, the accident might have happened — unlikely does not mean impossible — but there is no conclusive proof.

However, the *[Royal Gazette](http://www.royalgazette.com/article/20110511/NEWS/705119961)* has even more names and the location of the accident:

> Reader’s Digest reprints story of 1975 road deaths
>
> A bizarre tragedy reported in The Royal Gazette more than 35 years ago has resurfaced in the pages of this month’s Reader’s Digest.
>
> The July 21, 1975 issue of the newspaper carried a front page lead headlined, ‘Incredible coincidence in road crash deaths’.
>
> The same story appears in the current Reader’s Digest compilation entitled ‘What Are The Odds?’
>
> In an account that has circulated in publications and on the internet ever since, The Royal Gazette reports: “Erskine Ebbin and his brother Neville were killed almost exactly a year apart after being involved in collision with the same taxi, driven by the same driver and carrying the same passenger.”
>
> Both victims were 17, and both were riding the same auxiliary cycle on the same road.
>
> Erskine was killed on the night of July 18, 1975, near the Packwood Home in Sandys; Neville died on July 30, 1974, on the nearby stretch of Middle Road known as Hog Bay Level.
>
> Both were reported to have collided with a taxi driven by Willard Manders.
>
> According to their father, John Henry Ebbin of Woodlawn Road, Sandys, even the passenger in the taxi was the same in both instances.

Now that we have a source from Bermuda itself and a lot of verifiable data I tend to believe that it did indeed happen, though “at the same intersection” and “exactly a year apart” are exaggerations.

Comment: Bermuda registered births/deaths in 1975. In fact the law requiring registration was dated [1949](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGYQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bermudalaws.bm%2FLaws%2FConsolidated%2520Laws%2FRegistration%2520(Births%2520and%2520Deaths)%2520Act%25201949.pdf&ei=eQ5qU4P4Aeah0QXgyYDwCw&usg=AFQjCNHjFNhC9O0YMPePZ_y1Z8dSTy5Uyg&bvm=bv.66111022,d.d2k&cad=rja) so if the boys were aged 17 at death, then their birth *and* death would have been recorded. Could be possible to dig out of public records.

Comment: I checked the [Bermuda newspapers](http://cdm16347.contentdm.oclc.org/) from July/early August 1974 and there's no mention of a boy killed in a traffic accident. I also checked those from July 1975, but unfortunately the newspaper got discontinued exactly during mid-July 1975.

Comment: [Cracked](http://www.cracked.com/article_18788_the-5-most-mind-blowing-coincidences-all-time.html#ixzz312GU87cn) claimed to have verified it: "Before we go any further, please know that Cracked had to check with several overseas libraries and even the Library of Congress to verify this report."

Comment: ...and the best they could find was an article from a british newspaper published in a town of 72.000 residents. (No offense to Scunthorpians)

Comment: Also why the Library of Congress? Bermuda is not part of the US.

Comment: @drat The Library of Congress also has [foreign newspapers](http://www.loc.gov/rr/news/fncr.html) on file.

Comment: So it seems like it is either a true story or a locally-generated fraud that got spread?

Comment: I've seen the newspaper clipping. Correct me if you disagree, but it's not all that convincing -- looks easily created to me. Sure it *could* be all washed out from being a multiple-photo-copied copy... but I'd have figured one could have gotten a nice picture or perhaps full page image with the article in the context of the full page it appeared on.

Comment: Also, using real locations is not that convincing to me, either (for better or worse). If Cracked went through all the trouble to verify this, it would have been nice to have something like email transcripts, more photocopies, an explanation of *how* it was verified, etc. We have essentially the same story repeated with slightly better details. Could one have borrowed from another?

Comment: The real source is of course The Royal Gazette. And as far as I am concerned, it contains more than enough verifiable details to make a fake story unlikely.

Comment: The [16 August 1974 *Workers Voice* of Bermuda at page 3](https://bnl.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p16347coll2/id/313/rec/484) says: >The Union is saddened by the untimely
death of John Jr. , the son of Brother John
Ebbin (Construction Division) on August 1, 1974 and our sympathy is extended to the
family. John Jr. was taken from us at the very young age of 17 years where "Union" means the "Bermuda Industrial Union", the publisher of the newspaper.